# Как пишется "кто знает_ кто знает"?

Tags: запятые, тире

У нас есть две повторяющиеся фразы, разумно ли между ними ставить дефис (кто знает-кто знает)?
Или все-таки запятая, т. к. мы имеем дело с двумя предложениями, а не частями одного слова (кто знает, кто знает)?

Answer (score 4):

Между двумя повторяющимися словами пишется дефис, если образуется сложное слово, обычно с одним фонетическим ударением.

Сюда относятся **глаголы** со значением непрерывности процесса или интенсивности действия: ***просил-просил*** о помощи; На самой заре встанешь и **топчешься-топчешься** по избе: и воды надо принести, и печь растопить;
**глаголы** со значением действия, ограниченного каким-то отрезком времени:
***постоял-постоял*** и ушел; **Похожу-похожу** по двору, на улицу загляну и опять на печь лягу.

[Дефисное написание повторяющихся слов](http://lingvotech.com/povtordefis)

Это правило для нашего случая никак не подходит, поэтому ставим все-таки запятую.

> Для чего тогда затевалась техническая революция?
>   Я мог бы написать в ответ:
>   "Хочу красную пожарную машину".
>   **И кто знает, кто знает.**
>   (В. Пуханов)

*— **Кто знает, кто знает**, — промолвил трактирщик задумчиво* (А. К. Дойл. Затерянный мир).

Можно без потери смысла (задумчивости, растерянности, неуверенности) "разлучить" предложения в тексте — это тоже говорит в пользу раздельного написания.

***— Кто знает,*** — задумчиво протянул Джинн. — **Кто знает** (М. Фрай).